# How can I get a printer driver for Konica Minolta 165e?

Tags: drivers, printing

Where can I get a printer driver for Konica Minolta 165e on the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

if one looks for drivers on Open Printing;

On the Konica Minolta page, I can't see the bizhub 165e mentioned;

http://www.openprinting.org/printers/manufacturer/KONICA%20MINOLTA

However there are a lot of bizhubs that folks say work well;

eg http://www.openprinting.org/printer/KONICA%20MINOLTA/KONICA_MINOLTA-bizhub_1050

this page links to the postscript driver for Konica Minolta; and also links to a ppd file that one can download; I don't know how fluent you feel with all this; one can set up a driver by pointing Ubuntu to a ppd file; so I would suggest downloading the ppd file for bizhub 1050; then editing it; changing the references to bizhub1050 to bizhub 165e;

You can see in this link https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/where-are-ppd-files-stored-gentoo-ubuntu-337393/ that for ppd files

> The database is in /usr/share/ppd.

and

> installed ppds are in /etc/cups/ppd

so if you edited the ppd file; saved it to /usr/share/ppd (naming it 165e.ppd or such) then when you set up the printer; by going to ADD in the printers folder; and telling Ubuntu you want to use a ppd file; you point Ubuntu towards your 165e.ppd in /usr/share/ppd and .. it should work ..